# PHP mySQL Time Between Rows

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am stuck on this. Looking to be able to pull the time between 2 start/stop rows from a mySQL database. My table looks like this

```
fillercdown_ndx |  time                 | B3_4_5
1               |  2016-06-16 14:59:45  | 0
2               |  2016-06-16 15:03:11  | 1
```

Basically when its recorded as 0 the machine stopped and when the record is 1 the machine restarted. I need to be able to calculate the amount of time the machine was down between certain times like 8AM-5PM. Was going to use PHP to display it upon users time entered, but have no idea on the SQL command.

Anyone know the best way to be able to find this?

Create table

```
CREATE TABLE `fillercdown` (
 `fillercdown_ndx` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `B3_4_5` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`fillercdown_ndx`),
 KEY `fillercdowntimendx` (`time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

UPDATE:

There will be hundreds of these "start" and "stop" entries. My end all goal would be in php to give the user a small form asking them to provide a time range like 8AM-5PM and then be able to calculate all the time where the machine was "stopped" (which is when B3_4_5 is at 0). I just can't seem to figure out the right SQL call to get the time differences between each 0 and 1 and add them together between a set time range

Comment: I'm assuming that `fillercdown_ndx` is the primary key... could you add the `CREATE TABLE` for this table to your question? Also: do you want to a) know the duration until the next occurrence of a `1` from a specific `0`, i.e: do you know the `fillercdown_ndx` for it? b) from all? c) the average?

Comment: Updated I hope this explains more. Sorry I am really still learning, but trying my best. This just has me stuck

Comment: So if I understand the question correctly, you want to select all the pairs of (0,1) within the hours X and Y and then compute the sum of those intervals?

Comment: @Centril yes that is what I am trying to achieve if possible

Comment: Consider providing a more representative data set, a sample date range, AND a desired result.

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic idea... It selects the result into a single `row and`column`, which you can then fetch with`PHP`...

This solution assumes that stops & starts come in pairs, i.e: the ID of a start will be `+1` that of a stop. Otherwise you should `SELECT/JOIN` the ID that is `>` that of the stopped one, and `LIMIT` it to `1`.

A self join might not yield optimal performance wise, so be careful and measure execution times with some data to be on the safe side.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de72bf/1

```
CREATE TABLE fillercdown (
 `fillercdown_ndx` int(11)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `B3_4_5` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fillercdown_ndx`),
  KEY `fillercdowntimendx` (`time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO fillercdown
  (`time`, `B3_4_5`)
VALUES
  ('2016-06-16 14:00:45', 0),
  ('2016-06-16 14:01:00', 1),
  ('2016-06-16 16:00:00', 0),
  ('2016-06-16 16:01:00', 1)
  ;

SELECT SUM(TIMEDIFF(g.`time`, f.`time`))
FROM   fillercdown f
INNER JOIN fillercdown g
    ON g.`fillercdown_ndx` = (f.`fillercdown_ndx` + 1)
   AND g.`B3_4_5` = 1
   AND TIME(g.`time`) BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '17:00:00'
WHERE  f.`B3_4_5` = 0
   AND TIME(f.`time`) BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '17:00:00'
```

If you want to include times where the machine stopped but has not yet restarted, you can do something like this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d113b9/9

```
INSERT INTO fillercdown
  (`time`, `B3_4_5`)
VALUES
  ('2016-06-16 14:00:45', 0),
  ('2016-06-16 14:01:00', 1),
  ('2016-06-16 16:00:00', 0),
  ('2016-06-16 16:01:00', 1),
  ('2016-06-16 16:02:00', 0)
  ;

SELECT  SUM(TIMEDIFF(COALESCE(g.`time`, '2016-06-16 16:02:01'), f.`time`))
FROM    fillercdown f
LEFT JOIN fillercdown g
ON g.`fillercdown_ndx` = (f.`fillercdown_ndx` + 1)
   AND g.`B3_4_5` = 1
   AND TIME(g.`time`) BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '17:00:00'
WHERE   TIME(f.`time`) BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '17:00:00' AND f.`B3_4_5` = 0
```

You could replace `2016-06-16 16:02:01` with `NOW()` or something based on `f.time`, it depends on your application needs of course.

If you never want to get `NULL` but rather `0`, if there are no matching rows, then do something like: `COALESCE(SUM(...), 0)`.

If you prefer a scripted solution you can always do something like this:

```
SELECT  f.`time`, f.`B3_4_5`
FROM    fillercdown f
WHERE   TIME(f.`time`) BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '17:00:00'
```

And then compute the sum, like so (psuedocode):

```py
stopped = null;
pairs = []
for ( row in rows )
    if ( row.isStopped ) stopped = row
    else
        pairs += [stopped, row]
        stopped = null

sum = 0
for ( pair in pairs )
    sum += duration( pair[0], pair[1] )
```

Comment: You might want a LEAST and GREATEST in there somewhere

Comment: @Strawberry elaborate on that please, where? To make the result non-null if no matches are made, or?

Comment: This is awesome thank you! Now just to figure out how to make that psuedocode in to PHP

Comment: You're welcome, @Don't Panic s code is basically an implementation of the algorithm above... If you don't need to do anything else with the data other than to output the value the algorithm yields, you should really use the SQL version, since the IPC/Network costs will far exceed the computation time in PHP. A simple scalar value is much cheaper to transfer than potentially 100s or 100'000 rows. Plus, you can also make this into a `VIEW` and make it PHP-agnostic, which is always good...

Comment: @Centril the number returned would it just be in seconds?

Comment: @BryanVest Yes, this is what `TIMEDIFF` does... It returns the duration between 2 date(times) in seconds, and `SUM` is what you expect... If you want `NULL` results (no matching rows) to become `0`, you can always wrap `SUM(...)` in `COALECE(SUM(...), 0)`, but `NULL` might be useful to you to indicate that no rows matched. Test the sqlfiddle =)

Comment: @Centril would you know if there is an easy way to modify it so if there is no "start" row it adds the time from the last stop till the 5PM mark? Like if the machine was down at 2PM to 6PM, but we are pulling from 5PM it would add the 3 hours of being down?

Comment: Conceptually, this would instead be a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN` which would result in `g.\`time\` = NULL` which you then need to handle with `COALESCE(g.\`time\`, '2016-06-16 16:02:01')` or ` `COALESCE(g.\`time\`, NOW())`. I will update my answer shortly with these additions.

Comment: Updated my answer with a solution for that. If you found the answer useful, don't forget to up vote / mark as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am currently using to do the same thing it sounds like you're trying to do. I'm using PDO but this could be adapted fairly easily for mysqli if you need to use that. This depends on alternating off/on values by time. If there are any consecutive off or on rows for whatever reason, the expected result becomes ambiguous.

```
// First select everything in the requested range ordered by time.
$sql = "SELECT `time`, B3_4_5 FROM your_table WHERE `time` BETWEEN ? AND  ? ORDER BY `time`";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$query_start, $query_end]);

// Initialize two DateTime objects (start and end) used to calculate the total time.
$total_start = new DateTime('00:00');
$total_end = clone $total_start; 

$off = null;
while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
    if ($row->B3_4_5) {
        $on = new DateTime($row->time);
        // increment total end time with difference between current off/on times
        if ($off) {
            $total_end->add($on->diff($off));
        }
    } else {
        $off = new DateTime($row->time);
    }
}

// total downtime is difference between start and end DateTimes
$total_downtime = $total_start->diff($total_end);
```

`$total_downtime` is a `DateInterval` object. You can get return a message using its [`format`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) method:

```
echo $total_downtime->format('Total downtime: %h hours, %i minutes, %s seconds.');
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Gives me good direction and can work on modifying to fit.